# subprocess.communicate - read lines that are not newline terminated

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a Python program that uses the subprocess module to communicate with the admin interface of an appliance over ssh. Sometimes the appliance prompts for input with a line that's not newline terminated. How do I get subprocess.communicate() to return those lines to me? Is there a way to read unbuffered and character-by character? The amount of I/O generated is pretty small, so I'm not concerned about high overhead here.

Comment: An example will help you to get more answers

Comment: The [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library may save you some headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the process with `bufsize=0` will turn off output buffering according to [the subprocess docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) I think you'll still have to pass some custom file-like object (like a `StringIO`) into `Popen` as `stdout` or `stderr` and you'll have to read from those; `communicate()` waits for the process to terminate before it returns any of the command's output.